# I need to set only the month with @JsonFormat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

It is possible? I'm using

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate date;
```

to set my dates, but now I have a LocalDate to get just the month and another to get just the year.

I tried using

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy")
private LocalDate year;
```

but it didn't work, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

maven add jsr310

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

need to register module.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

sample out json

```
{"date":"03/08/2022","year":"2022"}
```